# How can Log4Net generates multiple log files for each test while running MsTest tests in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, log4net, mstest

I'm running MS tests in parallel and trying to generate separate log file for each test, using log4net.

I trying to generate log file dynamically by using a file name variable in the .config file.
I initialized the file name before creating the logger in the code.

```
  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="c:\temp\%property{TestName}" />

  public class BaseTest
{
    protected ILog log;
    public BaseTest()
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        ThreadContext.Properties["TestName"] = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name + ".log";
        log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    }
}
```

The goal is to create a separate log file for each test, the log file name should be the test name

Thanks

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?